# round cart total in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Round cart total if cart total is 31.47 then print 31 and if total is 31.50 or 31.51 more print total is 32 then how to achieve in woocommerce?

I tried this code :

```
function kncctr_custom_roundoff( $total ) {

        $round_num = round($total / 0.05) * 0.05;
        $total = number_format($round_num, 2); 
        // this is required for showing zero in the last decimal
        return $total;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code for round cart total

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_calculated_total', 'ak_calculated_total' );
function ak_calculated_total( $total ) {
$total = round( $total, 1 );
return ceil($total);
}
```

Comment: thank for your answer, i have updated this code and its working fine but I want to if total is 16.50 or above then result is 17 and if total is 16.49 or less then result is 16. hope you understood my concern

Comment: $total = round( $total); Use this for it

Comment: achieve this. thanks for your help

Comment: If this code is works for you, please mark it as green